# Intent.ACTION_PICK FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION on Nested Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

I need my users to select image from gallery to upload image to server. I've tried on an Activity and it works fine. But now I need the same codes on a child fragment (nested fragment). But this time, I always got this error when debugging. I even don't use any putExtra() into the intent.

```
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:23741283 intent:Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK typ=image/* }
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 2260252)
W/ActivityStopInfo: Bundle stats:
W/ActivityStopInfo:   android:viewHierarchyState [size=2268]
W/ActivityStopInfo:     android:views [size=2220]
W/ActivityStopInfo:   android:support:fragments [size=4888]
W/ActivityStopInfo: PersistableBundle stats:
W/ActivityStopInfo:   [null]
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xyz.student, PID: 12701
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2260252 bytes
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:160)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

ChildFragment.java

```
AlertDialog.Builder image = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
image.setMessage(R.string.select_method);
image.setPositiveButton(R.string.method_gallery,
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            imageMethod.dismiss();
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 7);
                }
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT_IMAGE);
            }
        }
    });
image.setNegativeButton(R.string.method_camera,
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            imageMethod.dismiss();
            captureImage();
        }
    });
imageMethod = image.create();
```

ParentFragment.java

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    final FragmentManager childFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    if (childFragmentManager != null) {
        final List<Fragment> nestedFragments = childFragmentManager.getFragments();
        if (nestedFragments == null || nestedFragments.size() == 0) return;
        for (Fragment childFragment : nestedFragments) {
            if (childFragment != null && !childFragment.isDetached() && !childFragment.isRemoving()) {
                childFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I always got this error`. And... which error exactly?

Comment: The whole error above in my Debug window. In particular, the error is `java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size`

Comment: Yes TransactionTooLargeException. What did you put in an intent?

Comment: LIke the above code, I only put `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);` and `intent.setType("image/*");`

Comment: And at which moment exactly you get that exception?

Comment: Right at the close parentheses of the `AlertDialog`. It even never hits the `onActivityResult()` yet.

Comment: ???? Do you mean when you just call startActivityForResult()? So when the user clicks the positive  button? Or do you mean when displaying the alert dialog?

Comment: `imageMethod.dismiss();` What is that?

Comment: `imageMethod.dismiss();` is to dismiss the dialog. I've put the whole AlertDialog

Comment: "Or do you mean when displaying the alert dialog?". Basically it is still in the dialog process. It happens after choosing the "Gallery App", not even select an image yet. The same thing happens when I chose Photos App (from Google), or File Manager App.

Comment: Your dialog is `image`. Not `imageMethod`. `image.dismiss();` i would think. And... who names a dialog an image? Unreadable code.

Comment: `imageMethod = image.create();`. Everything works fine in an Acitivity. I also have used the same dialog for First Fragment, and it works fine as well. Only in Nested Fragment I get the problem with.

Comment: And that you are telling now! Why not right away? And also confusing that you posted onActivityResult code. It is not even called you tell us now.

Comment: Sorry.. you told it before...

Comment: Something with the used context i think.

Comment: I posted the `onActivityResult()` on ParentFragment to show that I've put the correct behavior. Actually I also put the `super.onActivityResult()` in the Activity. Because by default, the Nested Fragment will call Activity then ParentFragment then Nested Fragment.

Comment: If the user has not selected an image yet or not pressed ok then onActivityResult is not called by the system. So it has nothing to do with your problem and hence posting code for it is irrelevant.